# Macbook Pro early 2015 Trackpad has no click. Screen flickers and trackpad and keyboard freeze after wake up, even after NVRAM and SMC reset

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, trackpad

The trackpad's click often fails during normal use.

It fails when the computer is used in a horizontal position flat on the table, but when the computer is tilted at a 45º angle the click starts working again.

The computer has gone to sleep twice in the middle of use.

Now every time I wake the computer up from sleep, the computer's screen flashes green or with a pixelated image, and the trackpad and keyboard do not work, so I have to force shutdown and do an SMC restart.

I was using El Capitan when the problems started, and now I have updated to High Sierra with no improvement.

I used cocnutBattery to assess the battery health in case of swelling, but it says the battery is completely healthy. Apple diagnostics also couldn't detect any problem.

I have tried the NVAM and SMC resets many times to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check with [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) - but it does sound like it's swollen.

Comment: I would suggest you run Apple Diagnostics and see if it reports an issues. Check here for more information on Apple Diagnostics: [How to use Apple Diagnostics on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin and Jake3231 for your advice, I've have tried your suggestions to no avail and so have re-edited the question.

Comment: coconutBattery cannot tell you if your battery is swelling.  This has to be done via visual inspection.